# android: to get the gas station name near specific latitude and longitude in 10 meters

Tags: android, android-listview

i am new to android and need help.
i have a situation in which i get latitude and longitude of gas station.
1.if the user visit to gas station, he must put the name of gas station which will store with the lat and longitude.
2.suppose the user visited to 10 gas stations. now if he visit to the gas station he already visited and stored the name in database.
3. the app should show him the name of the gas station in 10meters of range of lat and longitude.

i am confused i dont know what to do.
i can get the the lat and long and can store the name in database. but dont know how to get names in 10meter range of lat and long.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you already have stored all the lats and lons of the gas stations.

You could use the static function

`Location.distanceBetween(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, resultDistance)`

in a loop to check which of the gas stations stored are in a 10 meters distance from your current lat and lon. Just compare resultDistance[0] to see if its less or equal to 10.

According to Android docs:

> Computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations, and
>   optionally the initial and final bearings of the shortest path between
>   them. Distance and bearing are defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid.
>
> The computed distance is stored in results[0]. If results has length 2
>   or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results[1]. If results
>   has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results[2].

Hope this helps